# Получение значения по ключу

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно получить `TValue` по определенному `TKey` из заполненного словаря (класс `Dictionary`)?

Comment: ``myValue = myDictionary[myKey];`` или всё серъёзнее?

Comment: т.е. если я укажу уникальный ключ myKey в части "= myDictionary[myKey]" то в переменную myValue попадет значение из TValue соответсвующие этому ключу? просто не сталкивался, а в мсдне с циклами примры

Comment: [ну да](http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> myValue = myDictionary[myKey];

Спасибо [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre)